# pywebio не импортирует <script>

Tags: javascript, python

Я пробовал через pywebio создать script метку, но она не импортировала скрипт от desmos.
Код должен импортировать библиотеку. Просматривая HTML в странице заметил что импорт есть, но нужных методов нет.

```
   from pywebio.output import *
    
    class Desmos(object):
        """Desmos"""
        def __init__(self):
            super(Desmos, self).__init__()
            put_html("""<div id="calculator"></div><script src="//www.desmos.com/api/v0.8/calculator.js?apiKey=dcb31709b452b1cf9dc26972add0fda6"></script>""")
            put_html("""<script>
                      var elt = document.getElementById('calculator');
                      var calculator = Desmos.GraphingCalculator(elt);
                    </script>""")
        def add(self, lineOfText: str):
            put_html("<script>calculator.setExpression({latex: " + '"' + lineOfText +  '"' + "})</script>")
    
    desmos = Desmos()
    desmos.add("x=10")
    desmos.add("y=5")
    
    while True:
        desmos.add(input(':'))
```